# “An item with the same key has already been added” Error on SSRS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have a query which is running successfully in MS SQL Server 8 but I get the "item with the same key has already been added" error when trying to execute in Report Builder. Any help would be tremendously appreciated.

Here is my query:

```
DECLARE @firstDate DATETIME = ''
DECLARE @lastDate DATETIME = ''


DECLARE @inqtype VARCHAR(1000) = ''

SET @firstDate = '12/1/2016'
SET @lastDate = '12/3/2016'

SELECT  @firstDate, @lastDate, DATEDIFF(dd, @firstDate, @lastDate)
SELECT  @firstDate, @lastDate, DATEDIFF(HH, @firstDate, @lastDate)
SELECT  @firstDate, @lastDate, DATEDIFF(HH, CONVERT(time, @firstDate), CONVERT(time, @lastDate))
SELECT  @firstDate, @lastDate, DATEDIFF(MI, @firstDate, @lastDate)
SELECT  DATEPART(MI, @lastDate), DATEPART(MI, @firstDate)

SELECT
*
,CASE
WHEN minutes <= 1440 
THEN 'Yes'
WHEN minutes >= 1440 
THEN 'No'
END AS Compliance

FROM
(
select Distinct
INQ.FundCode,
INQ.County,
INQ.InquiryID,

CONT.FIRSTNAME, 
CONT.LASTNAME,
CONT.LASTNAME + ', ' + CONT.FIRSTNAME AS Worker,
supercontact.LASTNAME + ', ' + supercontact.FIRSTNAME as Supervisor,
INQ.Status,

INQ.Immediacy,
INQ.DateReceived,
INQ.InquirySource,
INQ.InqType,
INQ.EntryDate, 
INQ.EntryTime,
INQ.ScreeningDate, 
INQ.ScreeningTime,
  (DATEDIFF(DAY,INQ.EntryDate,INQ.ScreeningDate)) as days,
  (DATEDIFF(hour,INQ.EntryDate,INQ.ScreeningDate)) as hours,
  (DATEDIFF(Minute,INQ.EntryTime,INQ.ScreeningTime)) as minutes

from INQUIRY INQ
left join INQUIRYHistory intakeworker ON intakeworker.RECEIVEDBY = inq.RECEIVEDBY
left join HISPeople people ON people.MemberId = intakeworker.RECEIVEDBY
left join HISPeopleName intakeworkername ON people.PeopleId = intakeworkername.PeopleID
left join WORKERS work ON work.memberId = inq.RECEIVEDBY
left join CONTACT cont ON cont.ContactId= work.ContactId
left join HISInquiryLink inql ON inql.Datetimestamp=inq.DATETIMESTAMP

left join supervisors super WITH (NOLOCK) on work.MemberID = super.MEMBERID      
 and super.active = 1 and super.primarysuper = 1 and  super.StartDate <= GETDATE() and (super.EndDate > GETDATE()
 OR super.EndDate is NULL)  
left join workers superworker WITH (NOLOCK) on super.supervisor = superworker.memberid      
left join users su WITH (NOLOCK) on superworker.memberid =su.memberid    
left join contact supercontact WITH (NOLOCK) on superworker.contactid = supercontact.contactid

where 
INQ.EntryTime BETWEEN @firstDate AND @lastDate
AND INQ.InqType IN (@inqtype)
--AND INC.FundCode = 'ALL'
--AND work.active = 1
 )Temp
ORDER by Temp.EntryTime
```

Comment: Are you including all of this in you dataset query? The first 5 `SELECT` statements should not be in there.

Comment: yes remove first 5 select and put SET instead.if problem stil lthere then create fresh report with only this sql query and see what happen.